# Python: Add/edit annotations in images

Tags: python, image, annotations, polygon

There is an image and a multiset of pixel coordinates. Each set corresponds to a polygon.

The problem at hand is to overlay all the polygons onto the image, adjust their shapes/sizes to cover specific areas in the image and then save the resulting view of the image.

Suggestions on how to get started on this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I realize I was talking about image annotation. I found 'sloth'. I am giving it a try.

https://cvhci.anthropomatik.kit.edu/~baeuml/projects/a-universal-labeling-tool-for-computer-vision-sloth/